# Why audio files sound different?

Tags: java, audio

I recorded some audio files that must be played from java. I did it about half-year ago. Now, when I add files, they sound as if being sped-up with higher pitch. Old files sound normally, new ones don't. I suppose there is something that has to be changed in audio parameters. What could it be?

That's the code I'm using to play .wav files:

```
AudioInputStream result1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/home/nikkka/Desktop/alphabet/result.wav")); 
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, result1.getFormat());
Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(result1);
clip.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious ...

If the old file still play fine and the new ones don't, then it must be something different about the way that you *recorded* the new files.

It doesn't sound like the real problem is anything to do with programming, let alone Java.

---

> of course. but the thing is, i recorded the old files with settings i don't actually remember.

My suggestion is to fiddle with the settings until you can once again record files that play properly.

Comment: of course. but the thing is, i recorded the old files with settings i don't actually remember.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with your code. You just need to fiddle with the recording settings.

Comment: when i play files in player, they're normal

Comment: What is 'player'?  Note that most system players go to extraordinary lengths to make sense of poorly encoded data.  Just because a sound file 'plays OK' in the player, does not mean the sound file is encoded/written correctly.

Comment: ubuntu's default player. also, windows' media player.